# Is there any restriction on concurrent SQL Server connections posed by IIS server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, iis, iis-7

Is there any limit on the no. of simultaneous SQL connections by IIS server?

- Or is it solely dependent on the memory available?
- Or is there any other factor which would impose any restriction on the no. of concurrent SQL connections?

Comment: Is your application using ADO.NET?

Comment: see here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290441/number-of-concurrent-sql-server-connections

Comment: does it make any difference? what if YES and what if NO?

Comment: Actually I guess the clue should have been in your user name! Don't know if it makes any difference but figured if there **is** some maximum limit before you hit the SQL Server limit this might vary dependant upon technology used.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is, if you seem to be hitting a limit, you're doing something wrong. Are you getting errors indicating a limit has been reached?

Comment: something like "maximum pool size reached"..on a shared server...I think its connection pool limit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled via connection pooling which you can configure through web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you have your .NET code running in the web application properly designed to open and close immediately the connections after usage, the .NET connection pool will handle everything for you transparently.

it is my understanding that if you always use the **same connection string** only one connection will be created and managed and this is probably the best way to do it.

always avoid to keep any SQL Connection object opened and not closed or disposed immediately.

Comment: "... if you always use the same connection string only one connection will be created and managed..." ----is it really? I didn't know, connection string has got to do something with # of connections !!!

Comment: may be what you are telling about is connection-pool..but I think connection-pool and connection are not same, if I am not wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, see the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) here.

It's `32,767`. If you are hitting it you're probably not disposing connections.